# Laravel 5 - Dynamic Dependant Select Box using JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to develop a dynamic dependant select box using jQuery Ajax when trying to populate a list of rooms belonging to a hotel.

For example, when I select a hotel from the select box, the next select box should automatically show the rooms associated with that hotel.

However, when I try to implement that using Ajax, I get 500 Internal Server Error.

My Ajax Code is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("select[name='hotel_id']").change(function(){
      var hotel_id = $(this).val();
      var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
      $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo route('select-ajax') ?>",
          method: 'POST',
          data: {hotel_id:hotel_id, _token:token},
          success: function(data) {
            $("select[name='room_id'").html('');
            $("select[name='room_id'").html(data.options);
          }
      });
  });
```

Below also is the Laravel 5.2 controller for this project

```
public function selectAjax(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $hotel_rooms = DB::table('hotel_rooms')->where('hotel_id',$request->hotel_id)->pluck("id")->all();
            $data = view('ajax-select',compact('hotel_rooms'))->render();
            return response()->json(['options'=>$data]);
        }
    }
```

And below also is the ajax-select view.

```
<option>--- Select Room ---</option>
@if(!empty($hotel_rooms))
  @foreach($hotel_rooms as $key => $value)
    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

And finally, below is the create booking view with the two select options.

```
<label>Select Hotel:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="hotel_id">
            <option>-- Select Hotel -- {{ $hotels->count() }}</option>
            @foreach($hotels as $hotel)
                <option value="{{ $hotel->id }}">{{$hotel->hotel_name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

        <label>Select Room:</label>
      {!! Form::select('room_id',[''=>'--- Select Room ---'],null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us your error?

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/manage-bookings/create/select-ajax 500 (Internal Server Error) @usrNotFound

Comment: try dd'ing something in the controller first and do line by line debugging. Can you also put error message not juts 500. There are several reasons for 500.

Answer (score 0):

try to add _method: 'POST' in to your data

```
$.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo route('select-ajax') ?>",
      method: 'POST',
      data: {_method:'POST',hotel_id:hotel_id, _token:token},
      success: function(data) {
        $("select[name='room_id'").html('');
        $("select[name='room_id'").html(data.options);
      }
  });
```